# Celsius to Fahrenheit Conversion Form

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a form that will convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa, but I am running into an error with the Conversion buttons code. The problem I am getting is that the variable convertedTemperature is left empty, so that should validation fail the message will be displayed via the ouput label(lblConvertedTemperature). But because of this being left blank I get the use of unassigned variable error. My question is how can I reword the processing section to not cause this error.

```
        Double inputTemperature;// the variable that will store txtTemperatureInput for calculation
        Double convertedTemperature;// the variable that will store the converted temperature



        /*********************************
         * INPUT                         *
         * *******************************/
        // when the user inputs a value and clicks calculate, the input must first be validated
        if (Double.TryParse(txtTemperatureInput.Text, out inputTemperature) == false)
        {
            lblConvertedTemperature.Text = "Temperature must be a numeric value.";// message displayed in 
            //output label telling user their input was not accepted because it was not numeric
            txtTemperatureInput.Focus();// sets the focus back onto the temperature textbox for a new entry
        }
        else
        {
            /*******************************
             * PROCESSING                  *
             *******************************/
            if (optConvertToCelsius.Checked == true)// if the convert to celsius radio button is selected
            // this statement will run
            {
                convertedTemperature = (inputTemperature - 32)*5 / 9;// the formula for converting 
                //Fahrenheit to Celsius

            }
            else if (optConvertToFahrenheit.Checked == true)// convert to fahrenheit was selected, 
            //meaning the convert to fahrenheit radio button was selected, so this statement will run
            {
                convertedTemperature = (inputTemperature * 9) / 5 + 32; ;// the formula for converting Celsius to
                //Fahrenheit
            }//end concatonated if
        }//end if
            /******************************
             *OUTPUT                      *
             ******************************/
            lblConvertedTemperature.Text = Math.Round(convertedTemperature, 4).ToString();// sets the converted temperature
            // label to the value of convertedTemperature

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is how can I reword the processing section to not cause this error.

Well, there are two situations that the compiler is concerned about:

- If the input is invalid, you're already changing `lblConvertedTemperature.Text` anyway... so just return after you've done that. (You then don't need an `else` clause, which means you'll have less nesting - always nice for readability.)
- Neither `optConvertToCelsius` nor `optConvertToFahrenheit` is checked. That's a situation the *compiler* considers, because you've got two separate conditions that you're checking. You may know it's never going to happen, of course.

For the latter, I'd suggest just removing the second condition:

```
if (optConvertToCelsius.Checked)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

Note that I've removed the `== true` from the first condition just as a matter of style.

Now the compiler will know that if you get to this point, *one* of those two blocks will be executed. As both blocks assign to `convertedTemperature`, the variable will be definitely assigned at the end of that code.

EDIT: Just to clarify, if you have:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    ...
} 
else if (someOtherCondition)
{
    ...
}
```

the compiler will *not* assume that one of those blocks will be executed, regardless of what the conditions are. Even if *you* know that exactly one condition will be true, the compiler just follows its relatively-simple rules.

Comment: Celsius is auto selected, so there should never be a case where neither radiobtns are selected.

Comment: @Ryan: It may never happen in reality, but the *compiler* doesn't know that. Just like you could have: `if (x > 0) { ... } else if (x <= 0) { ... }` and the compiler still wouldn't know that one or other of those branches would be taken. The compiler doesn't try to work out what your UI would do - it just follows the rules of the language specification.

Comment: Okay so I changed the code to fit into your structure, but I would prefer to have there only be the two situations, as there are no specifications as to what the program should do if neither are selected.

Comment: @Ryan: Right, and that's what my code shows... two situations. `if (optConvertToCelsius.Checked) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: Just realized that... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You're scoping looks off.  Simply move

```
         /******************************
         *OUTPUT                      *
         ******************************/
        lblConvertedTemperature.Text = Math.Round(convertedTemperature, 4).ToString();// sets the converted temperature
        // label to the value of convertedTemperature
```

To the "processing" scope.

Comment: That's not enough on its own, as it still won't be definitely assigned... there's `if (...) { } else if (...) { }` so the compiler will assume that it's possible for neither block to be executed.

Comment: That's only true if neither are selected, and outside scope of OP.  It also says it's a radio button, which, providing it's setup properly will always be 1 or the other as is the nature of radio buttons.

Comment: You've missed my point. The code will still generate a compile-time error, because the variable won't be classified as definitely assigned when it tries to read from it. See my comments on my answer. If the code doesn't compile, any discussion of what will happen at execution-time is moot...